# MySQL 8: Query Performance between subquery with GROUP BY and INNER JOIN with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have to retrieve a list of postings, by one or more category IDs.
I do not want to have duplicate postings in my results.

I'm only interested in responses that directly relate, or can draw relations with MySQL 8

There are two queries I'm considering, and I'm deciding which one is better.  Or, if there is a better "3rd query", please advise.

Consider a simple two table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `job_category_posting` (
  `category_posting_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_posting_category_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_posting_posting_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_posting_is_primary_category` tinyint UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `job_posting` (
  `posting_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `posting_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `posting_body` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE `job_category_posting`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_posting_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `category_posting_category_id` (`category_posting_category_id`,`category_posting_posting_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `category_posting_is_primary_category` (`category_posting_is_primary_category`,`category_posting_posting_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_posting_posting_id` (`category_posting_posting_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `job_posting`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`posting_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `posting_reserve_id` (`posting_reserve_id`),
  ADD KEY `posting_title` (`posting_title`);
```

---

**1st query (SUBQUERY with GROUP BY):**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM job_posting AS t1
WHERE (t1.posting_id) IN(
   SELECT category_posting_posting_id
   FROM job_category_posting
   WHERE category_posting_category_id IN (2,13,22,23,24,25)
   GROUP BY category_posting_posting_id
)
```

Quick dirty speed tests (doesn't tell me much):

- 0.0017 seconds
- 0.0016 seconds
- 0.0011 seconds
- 0.0017 seconds

EXPLAIN gives me this:
[image: 1st query using subquery]

What I noticed:

- Query plan has gone through quite a number of rows (2356 + 1 + 1935) to get the result
- No temporary table.  Uses just index.

---

**2nd query (INNER JOIN with GROUP BY):**

```
 SELECT job_posting.*
 FROM job_category_posting
 inner join job_posting on job_category_posting.category_posting_posting_id = job_posting.posting_id
 WHERE category_posting_category_id IN (2,13,22,23,24,25)
GROUP BY category_posting_posting_id
```

Quick dirty speed tests (doesn't tell me much):

- 0.0016 seconds
- 0.0011 seconds
- 0.0010 seconds
- 0.0019 seconds

EXPLAIN gives me this:
[image: 2nd query using join]

What I noticed:

- Query plan has gone through only 1935 + 1 rows
- But it uses temporary table

---

So my question is, which is better?  Is there a better explanation that can justify it?  I just need some solid facts and proof.

Or is there a third query I should try?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Both queries are either invalid SQL or else make no sense.  Therefore, we cannot "optimize" anything.  You should add sample data to better explain what you are doing here.

Comment: See this for a way to more precisely gauge which is faster (by counting rows touched):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. You have appropriate indexes for both your queries.
2. Execution plans often change as tables grow. The work you do to save a few hundred microseconds on a small table is not necessarily useful for a larger table. You'll probably need to revisit execution plans as your tables grow.
3. "Using temporary" doesn't mean your query uses a full-blown on-disk temporary table. It simply means the software accumulates a result set into a temporary data structure prior to, in your case, deduplicating it. (Only if that temporary data structure is too big for RAM does the software use on-disk structures. Yours certainly fits in RAM.) Don't be fooled by the inaccurate, but time-honored, language in the execution plan's `extra` column. "Using temporary" is OK.
4. The `value IN (set of values)` predicate automatically deduplicates the set of values. So your first query can be rewritten without the GROUP BY thusly.

   ```sql
   SELECT t1.*
     FROM job_posting AS t1
    WHERE t1.posting_id IN (
           SELECT category_posting_posting_id
             FROM job_category_posting
            WHERE category_posting_category_id IN (2,13,22,23,24,25)
          )
   ```

   This is the query I would use, because (in my opinion) it expresses your intent most clearly. And, I suspect it scales up better to large tables because it does the deduplication work on the set of `posting_id` values alone, not whole rows.
5. Your second query misuses MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause. Better yet, get rid of the GROUP BY and use DISTINCT, like this.

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT job_posting.*
     FROM job_category_posting
    inner join job_posting
        on job_category_posting.category_posting_posting_id = job_posting.posting_id
    WHERE category_posting_category_id IN (2,13,22,23,24,25)
   ```

   But this has to deduplicate whole rows.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation!  That shed me some light and I know which direction to head now.

Answer (score 0):

- `job_category_posting` seems to be a many-to-many mapping table.  If so, the indexes you have are sub-optimal.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- See this for a way to more precisely gauge which is faster (by counting rows touched): mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts
- Avoid using `IN ( SELECT ... )`; it is usually sub-optimal.  `JOIN` or `EXISTS` is usually better.
- Since the `GROUP BY` seems to apply to one table, try this formulation:

  ```
    SELECT ...
        FROM ( SELECT ... GROUP BY ... ) AS a
        JOIN ... AS b  ON ...
  ```

  That way, the subquery shrinks the number of rows to look at *before* reaching into the other table.